# Simple linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$xy'=x+y$$

$y'=1+\frac{y}{x}$

$y'=1+\frac{y}{x}$

$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x}$

$\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$

Integrating both sides will not be useful as $\int \frac{1}{y}$ is unknown, how should I procced?

Comment: **Hint:** Try an Integrating Factor, since you have $y' - \dfrac{y}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @Moo $M(x)=e^{\int -\frac{1}{x}}$?

Comment: This is LDE and try with the integrating factor.

Comment: @gbox: Exactly.

Comment: @Moo the ODE must be in normal form to use these integrating factor?

Comment: @gbox: Read the third statement and look at equation (1): http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite as the 1$^{st}$ order linear ode 
 $$ y' - \frac{1}{x} y = 1$$
Now we seek an integrating factor $\mu(x)$ such that the LHS becomes the result of a product rule. 
$$\mu(x) = \exp \int - \frac{1}{x} ~\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{x}$$
After multiplying through by $\mu(x)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x} y' - \frac{1}{x^2} y &= \frac{1}{x} \\
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left[ \frac{1}{x} y \right] &= \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}

Integrating both sides and solving for $y$ gets you home.